# Split np.where series (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on a numpy script, it should find the maximum value for the indexes provided by `np.where` but only when they are "consecutive".
I try to explain:

```
RsiMa = ...array calculations...
RsiMa_1 = np.roll(RsiMa, 1)
longband = ...array calculations...
longband_1 = np.roll(longband, 1)

long_max = np.where(((RsiMa_1 > longband_1) & (RsiMa > longband_1)))
```

Arrays:

```
               0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8       9
RsiMa         50     51     51     51     50     47     50     50     51      50
RsiMa_1       50     50     51     51     51     50     47     50     50      51
longband      49     49     48     47     50     46     45     44     52      50
longband_1    50     49     49     48     47     50     46     45     44      52
long_max   False   True   True   True   True  False   True   True   True   False
```

Now, what I expect (wrongly) if I call `longband[long_max] = np.max(longband[long_max])` is that:

```
long_max             False   True   True   True   True  False   True   True   True   False
longband[long_max]      49     49     49     49     50     46     45     45     52      50
```

Instead I recive that when `long_max` is `True`, `longband[long_max]` is equal to the absolute maximum value at the provided indexes (52):

```
longband[long_max]  49   52   52   52   52   46   52   52   52   50
```

How I can recognize the long_max's True series WITHOUT LOOPS and apply them to `np.max`?